# Probability Distribution of a standard normal distribution with absolute value

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Z is a standard normal and we have to prove that

\begin{equation} P(|z| \geq s) \leq {\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}} {\frac{e^{\frac{-s^{2}}{2}}}{s}}\end{equation}

As far as I understand I have to use the formula for distribution function of a standard normal random variable, but I do not know how to deal with the ≥ inequality in the probability function as I have only seen examples with the ≤  inequality.

Comment: "I do not know how to deal with the ≥ inequality": Well, you can always use $P(X \geq z) = 1-P(X < z)$...

Comment: Consider the complement event: $P(|z| \ge s) = 1- P(|z|< s)$.

Comment: @Florian Sorry but, what for?

Comment: @Crostul Sorry but, what for?

Comment: @Did: well you had asked how to convert $\geq$ into $\leq$, this is how. But as you see in the answer by Mau314, this was not even necessary to begin with.

Comment: @Florian What are you talking about? First, I never asked this, second this is not useful to solve the question.

Comment: @Did: Well, you said "I do not know how to deal with the $\geq$ inequality in the probability function as I have only seen examples with the $\leq$ inequality". You are asked to bound $P(|z|\geq x)$. This is equal to $1-P(|z|<x)$ which for a continuous random variable is equal to $1-P(|z|\leq x)$. Now the question only has a $\leq$ inequality which you claimed to be familiar with. If this does not solve your problem this tells you that you did not give us enough information (or your question misled us). You could for instance haven shown us how you would treat the $\leq$ case.

Comment: @Florian You seem to be taking me for Albertine. I can assure you I am not.

Comment: @Did Oh jeez, I'm sorry. For some reason I thought it's the OP replying. Will pay better attention next time! But still, I guess you get what I meant: the OP particularly asked about the $\geq$ inequality, implying that things would be simple if a $\leq$ was there. So we provided the conversion, allowing the OP to apply her knowledge about the $\leq$ case herself. If this does not help then ideally it would have led the OP to improve the question, realizing that the $\geq$ was not actually the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do it without considering the complement; you can prove this by studying explicitly the corresponding integral: For $s\geq 0$, we have
$$P(|Z|\geq s)=2\int_s^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x.$$
Now via transformation you can artificially introduce a factor that corresponds to $\frac{1}{x}$. This factor can be bounded by $\frac{1}{x}\leq\frac{1}{s}$ and you can integrate the remaining $\exp(\cdot)-$term as usual.

In more detail, choose the transformation $z:=\frac{x^2}{2}$. Then the right hand side above is equal to
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{s^2/2}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 z}}\exp(-z)\mathrm{d}z.$$
Now, using $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2z}}\leq\frac{1}{s}$ we obtain
$$P(|Z|\geq s)\leq \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{s}\int_{s^2/2}^\infty \exp(-z)\mathrm{d}z=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{s}\exp\left(-\frac{s^2}{2}\right).$$